# Gradle Error when Renaming Packages

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, package

I'm trying to rename a package in an app I'm making in Android Studio. I did Refactor>Rename on the package, but when I build the project, I get this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/example/drawingApp/customViews/DrawingView) does not match path (com/example/drawingApp/Views/DrawingView.class)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/example/drawingApp/Views/DrawingView.class
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I also tried creating a new package and dragging the class into it, but that produced the same error. How do I fix this?

Comment: what `android:package=""` have you defined, I guess they must match to each other. Or perform "gradle clean" before you rebuild.

Comment: Thanks! Performing gradle clean fixed the problem.